# Ignore part of a line which contains certain text

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
https:\\somegif.some\some-random-gif.gif *textinbetween?!@* abc-abc-abc
def-def-def
a something: 123-456-789-101
```

I need to get all the strings that matches this RegEx `([\w]+(\s*-\s*[\w]+){2,3})`.

This is the code I use to get those strings:

```
import re

test_str = ("https:\\\\somegif.some\\some-random-gif.gif *textinbetween?!@* abc-abc-abc\n"
            "def-def-def\n"
            "a something: 123-456-789-101\n")
regex = r"([\w]+(\s*-\s*[\w]+){2,3})"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:
    match = match.group()
    match = match.replace(" ", "")
    print(match)
```

This will output:

```
some-random-gif
abc-abc-abc
def-def-def
123-456-789-101
```

I don't need `some-random-gif`. How can I filter that.
I could use something like this:

```
nohttp = str()
for line in test_str.split('\n'):
    if 'http' not in line:
        nohttp += line + '\n'
```

But it will also remove `abc-abc-abc`.

Comment: If you don't want to match `gif` in the repeated group you could use a negative lookahead `\w+(?:\s*-\s*(?!gif\b)\w+){2,3}`

Comment: @Thefourthbird `some-random-gif` could be anything. I only used it for example.

Comment: @conquistador what about `[\w-]+(?=\n)`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're trying to ignore the url and its contents when your regex is matching - this makes sense, as the url could potentially have a structure that matches your pattern.

One possible solution is to use a regex to remove the url from the string before searching; given that there appears to be whitespace between the end of the url and the beginning of the text you want to match, you can match non-whitespace characters starting at the beginning of the string, checking to make sure they begin with "http" or "https".

```py
import re

instring = ("https:\\\\somegif.some\\some-random-gif.gif *textinbetween?!@* abc-abc-abc\n"
            "def-def-def\n"
            "a something: 123-456-789-101\n")

newstring = re.sub('^https?:\S*','',instring)

regex = r"([\w]+(\s*-\s*[\w]+){2,3})"

matches = re.finditer(regex, newstring, re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:
    match = match.group()
    match = match.replace(" ", "")
    print(match)
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/MurkyReadyMachinecode)

If the URL is always present in your test string and is always the first "word", you could simply use `^\S*` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell why `some-random-gif` shouldn't match.

This will match items that are between whitespace *boundary's*:

`(?<!\S)[\w]+(?:\s*-\s*[\w]+){2,3}(?!\S)`

https://regex101.com/r/v7cMAv/1